# All possible combinations of a set as a list of strings

Tags: python, set, python-itertools

I am trying to write a function in Python

```
def all_strings(alpha,length):
    # ...
```

which takes a given alphabet (`alpha`) and a `length` and returns all possible combinations of the alphabet restricted by the given length.

For example:

```
all_strings({0,1}, 3)
```

should return:

```
['000', '001', '010', '011', '100', '101', '110', '111']
```

I tried looping through the set but you cannot iterate through a set in python. I also considered itertools however `permutations` and `combinations` do not allow repetition of numbers.

Comment: `itertools.product`!

Comment: Why do you say you can't iterate through a set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> from itertools import product

>>> list(product({0,1}, repeat=3))
[(0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 1),
 (0, 1, 0),
 (0, 1, 1),
 (1, 0, 0),
 (1, 0, 1),
 (1, 1, 0),
 (1, 1, 1)]
```

You can also [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) the results to get the strings:

```
>>> list(''.join(map(str, comb)) for comb in product({0,1}, repeat=3))
['000', '001', '010', '011', '100', '101', '110', '111']
```

And if you care about efficiency one can also convert the initial set to a set of strings to minimize the string conversions (thanks @Stefan Pochmann for pointing this out in the comments):

```
>>> list(map(''.join, product(map(str, {0,1}), repeat=3)))
['000', '001', '010', '011', '100', '101', '110', '111']
```

Comment: I have done the following `from itertools import product
def all_strings(alpha,length):
  return_list = list(product(alpha,repeat=length))
  return return_list` Can I get it to return the list as `['000', '001', '010'....` Rather than `[(0,0,0),(0,0,1)....`

Comment: The second part of the answer, the one about the `str.join`, shows just that: `list(''.join(map(str, comb)) for comb in product(alpha, repeat=length))`

Comment: `list(map(''.join, product(map(str, {0,1}), repeat=3)))` should be faster because it converts to strings only once and maybe also because of `map` instead of the generator expression.

Comment: @StefanPochmann You're right that's definetly much faster! I edited the answer.